# Prove two angles on tangents of two circles are equal

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

> **Question:**
>
> ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral.
>
> Circle $DCJ(P)$ is tangent to $AB$ at $J$.
>
> Circle $ABK(O)$ is tangent to $DC$ at $K$.
>
> Prove $\angle BJK=\angle CKJ$.

---

**Attempt**

Extend $AB$ and $DC$ so that they meet at point $E$, then the question is equivalent to prove $EJ =EK$. Now, by the [Power of a Point Theorem](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/PPower.shtml), we know the following:
$$EA\cdot EB= EK^2\\
EC\cdot ED=EJ^2 $$

I saw [PPL: Apollonius' Problem with Two Points and a Line](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/PPL.shtml) but I don't know how to use here.

***Note***: Please share your ideas and your attempts in comments or even answer if your solution is not complete. Thanks!

Comment: Let us rewrite the problem equivalently. We start with two circles $(O)$ and $(P)$ that intersect and take one more point $E$ exterior to the two circles. Then is it true that from $E$ we always **equal tangents** ($EJ$ and $EK$ in the picture) to the two circles?!

Comment: OK, now we also have an assumption about ABCD, well..

Comment: (Please post next time everything in a breath, at least the essential part, later edits may confuse readers, that immediately start to type a solution / to given an answer, especially when important, non-cosmetics parts of the statement show up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original post is only missing the equality $$EA\cdot EB=EC\cdot ED\ ,$$
which follows from $ABCD$ being inscribed in a circle.

---

Picture and solution for the problem, putting all together:

[image: Problem 2923985 MSE geometry]

Let $E$ be the point of intersection $AB\cap CD$. Then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
EJ^2 
&= EC\cdot ED &&\text{(Power of $E$ w.r.t circle $(JCD)$)}
\\
&= EB\cdot EA &&\text{(Power of $E$ w.r.t circle $(ABCD)$)}
\\
&=EK^2 &&\text{(Power of $E$ w.r.t circle $(ABK)$)}
\end{aligned}
$$
so $EJ=EK$, the triangle $\Delta EJK$ is isosceles in $E$, so its angles in $J,K$ are equal.

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

Let $JK\cap arc DC=\{N\}$.

Thus, $\measuredangle KJB=\measuredangle JDN$ and if $\measuredangle KJB=\measuredangle JKC$, we obtain
$$\measuredangle JDN=\measuredangle DJN+\measuredangle JDK,$$ which gives
$$\measuredangle NDC=\measuredangle DJN,$$ which says that $N$ is a mid-point of the arc $DC$, which is not necessary if not given that $ABCD$ is cyclic.